# Using toFixed(2) and math round to get correct rounding

Tags: javascript, rounding

I would like to find a function that will return this kind of formatted values :

```
1.5555 => 1.55
1.5556 => 1.56
1.5554 => 1.55
1.5651 => 1.56
```

toFixed() and math round return this value :

```
1.5651.fixedTo(2) => 1.57
```

This will be usefull for money rounding.

Comment: You have the fourth decimal affect the second decimal? When ever would you use this?

Comment: Why would you want to round in such a strange way? How would this be useful for money rounding?

Comment: Your examples don't really seem to be getting your point across. What's the rule you're trying to enforce, exactly? Round down on a final "5" digit, unless the next digit is > 5?

Comment: Indeed, this is a strange way of rounding. Doesn't really make any sense to me.

Comment: Isn't that how Richar Pryor made all that money in that Superman movie?

Comment: @adrien334: Thanks for ignoring all our comments completely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
function wacky_round(number, places) {
    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, places+2); // get two extra digits
    var fixed = Math.floor(number*multiplier); // convert to integer
    fixed += 44; // round down on anything less than x.xxx56
    fixed = Math.floor(fixed/100); // chop off last 2 digits
    return fixed/Math.pow(10, places);
}
```

> 1.5554 => 1.55
>
> 1.5555 => 1.55
>
> 1.5556 => 1.56
>
> 1.5651 => 1.56

So, that works, but I think you'll find that it's not a generally-accepted way to round.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste error while formatting for the site. Oh, and you're clear on why you shouldn't use this rounding method, right?

Comment: it was not for my consumption ;) however the one [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535394/round-off-decimal-using-javascript) wanted to round amounts from .181 to .18 and .185 to .19 which I am never so sure of. toFixed(2) feels wrong in these cases.

Answer (score 3):

And standard function

```
fixedTo = function (number, n) {
  var k = Math.pow(10, n);
  return (Math.round(number * k) / k);
}
```

and then call

```
fixedTo(1.5555, 2)  // 1.56
fixedTo(1.5555, 2)  // 1.556
fixedTo(0.615, 2)   // 0.62
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for `1.005`. I recommend using [this function instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23204425/573634)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native Number.toFixed() method.

```
parseFloat(10.159.toFixed(2))
```

The above returns 10.16. Number.toFixed() returns a string, so I use parseFloat to convert it to a number.