# Javascript Rounding issues

Tags: javascript

I tried using this:

```
//var value = "39.99";
//var value = "0.255";
var list = ["39.99", "0.255", "0.306", "0.645", "2.505", "5.726", "9.649", "9.999", "10.01", "0.155", "0.355", "10.05", "14.75", "14.02", "2.405", "14.54","2.485"];


var result;

for( i in list ){
    //result = processRounding(parseFloat(list[i]).toFixed(3));
    //result = parseFloat(list[i]).toFixed(2);
    result = test(parseFloat(list[i]).toFixed(3), 2);
    console.log("RESULT["+i+"]: "+ format("#,##0.00", result));
}

function test(value, precision) {
    var precision = precision || 0,
    neg = value < 0,
    power = Math.pow(10, precision),
    value = Math.round(value * power),
    integral = String((neg ? Math.ceil : Math.floor)(value / power)),
    fraction = String((neg ? -value : value) % power),
    padding = new Array(Math.max(precision - fraction.length, 0) + 1).join('0');

    return precision ? integral + '.' +  padding + fraction : integral;
}


function processRounding (value){
    //console.log( Math.ceil(value*100) + " " +  Math.ceil(value*100) / 2);
    var remainder = parseFloat(value % 1).toFixed(2);
    var floor     = parseInt(Math.floor(value));
    console.log(floor + " " + remainder);
    if(Math.floor(value) != 0 && Math.floor(value) > 10){
        if( parseFloat(remainder) > 0.50 || parseFloat(remainder) > 0.05 ){
            console.log("CEIL");
            value = Math.ceil(value*10)/10;
        }else{
            value = value;
        }          
    }else{
        if( parseFloat(remainder) > 0.50 || parseFloat(remainder) > 0.05 ){
            console.log("ROUND");
            value = Math.round(value*100)/100;
        }else{
            value = value;
        } 
    }

    return value;
}
```

[[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aabanaag/2JaRY/2/)]

But the problem I see is that when the value is something like `"2.405"` what it does is simple make it "2.40" regardless if I use either the function `test` or the function `processRounding` in my jsfiddle example.

Any Ideas on how to make the result into 2.41? Technically It should round up right since the last digit is "5".

**UPDATE**

using `result = test(parseFloat(list[i]).toFixed(3), 2);`

```
var list = ["39.99", "0.255", "0.306", "0.645", "2.505", "5.726", "9.649", "9.999", "10.01", "0.155", "0.355", "10.05", "14.75", "14.02", "2.405", "14.54","2.485"];
```

would result to this :

```
RESULT[0]: 39.99
RESULT[1]: 0.26 
RESULT[2]: 0.31 
RESULT[3]: 0.65 
RESULT[4]: 2.51 
RESULT[5]: 5.73 
RESULT[6]: 9.65 
RESULT[7]: 10.00 
RESULT[8]: 10.01 
RESULT[9]: 0.16 
RESULT[10]: 0.36
RESULT[11]: 10.05
RESULT[12]: 14.75
RESULT[13]: 14.02
RESULT[14]: 2.40
RESULT[15]: 14.54
RESULT[16]: 2.49
```

Notice that in the list there is a "2.405" value which in the result[14] it is "2.40" it should be in 2.41 right?

Comment: there's a lot going on in that fiddle.  Can you post the relevant section here?

Answer (score 3):

I think you wish to have a round off function in JavaScript.

```
function trueRound(value, digits){
    return (Math.round((value*Math.pow(10,digits)).toFixed(digits-1))/Math.pow(10,digits)).toFixed(digits);
}
```

Possibly duplicated question: [round off decimal using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535394/round-off-decimal-using-javascript)

Comment: okay it did work. but my question is how about the value 39.99 it should be rounded off to 40 right?

Comment: To round a number to the nearest integer: `Math.round(x)`

Comment: @Dreyfus15 It works that way for me testing it just now... trueRound(39.99,1) returns 40.0

Comment: I'm using this trueRound(parseFloat(value).toFixed(2), 2) simply because 0.255 should be rounded off to 0.26 not 0.30

Answer (score 0):

You're starting off by cutting the remainder off to 2 decimals: `parseFloat(value % 1).toFixed(2);`

That means when you have `2.405` the remainder is parsed as `.40` and it won't be able to differentiate between 2.400 and 2.409

You're going to want to keep the full remainder if you want to round that correctly.

Roger Ng has a good solution.   I just wanted to explain why yours has no chance of working from the start.

Comment: I also tried using toFixed(3) to be able to retrieve .405 yet same results.