# JavaScript division issue

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript long division program that prompts the user to enter a divisor and a dividend and also the number of decimal places to give the result in.

In JavaScript, when I divide the following I get the result:

```
60.30 / 5 = 12.059999999999999
```

but using a calculator I get:

```
12.06
```

Is there an issue with JavaScript?

If I use `toFixed` that works in this instance, but if the numbers are as follows:

```
603.00000 / 55 = 10.96364
```

where the calculator results in:

```
10.963636363636363636363636363636
```

I know that `toFixed` rounds the number but the rounding results in an incorrect answer on the second example.

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: That would be the floating points issue, present in all computers.

Comment: If you need a [trueRound(value, digits)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535394/round-off-decimal-using-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top) function