# toFixed(2) rounds "x.525" inconsistently?

Tags: javascript, rounding

I'm experiencing rounding errors when using toFixed:

I used `toFixed(2)` on my numeric value calculations, but the rounding results are not as expected for few cases.

Suppose that `toFixed(2)` is applied for value `17.525` then it gives the result `17.52`, And if it is applied for `5.525` then it gives the result `5.53`.

In the later case the rounding result is accurate, so can you please suggest what needs to be done to get the accurate rounding result as in the later case. Or can you please suggest an alternative to this toFixed function to get correct rounding results?

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with jQuery. It's a JavaScript function https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed.

Comment: That result is perfectly okay. Mantissa-exponent floating point numbers are a lie. Try `toFixed(20)` and then compare.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using toFixed(2) and math round to get correct rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861055/using-tofixed2-and-math-round-to-get-correct-rounding)

Comment: I believe that if you execute `17.525.toFixed(2)` you'll get `17.53` (I do) and so the result of `17.52` is produced from another value, less than 17.525.

Comment: Oops, please don't close for that "duplicate". It's similar, but that's for a specific rounding case. There ought to be a better one!

Comment: @panda-34: I got 17.52 in Firefox (Windows).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861055/using-tofixed2-and-math-round-to-get-correct-rounding (similar idea)

Comment: @nhahtdh Yeah, on a second thought, it's probably a bug in my system. 17.52 is the correct result according to ECMA specification. I'm not sure that I don't like this microsoft's bug because it does make sense.

Comment: I think it's only inconsistent in some browsers (IE11 seems consistent, FF and Chrome are inconsistent).See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23204425/573634) for a function that works across all browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floating point inaccuracy means that most numbers ending .525 are actually .52500..1, and others are .5249999.....

Which way the value rounds depends on whether the closest actual representation in IEEE-754 floating point is above or below the desired value.

Comment: `17.525.toFixed(3)`
`"17.525"` Dropping the last digit gives `"17.52"` which is wrong? I get different results in different browsers though, so I doubt `toFixed` is any good :P

Comment: @Esailija no, I think 17.52 would be a valid response in that case.

Comment: @Alnitak maybe I misunderstood the OP then because he said that's wrong... but OTOH he accepted this so what do I know :)

Comment: @Esailija yeah, and I just realised it does the wrong thing for 17.529 too.  Hmm.

Comment: @Alnitak there is also differences between browsers, for me `17.525.toFixed(2)` is `"17.52"` in chrome but `"17.53"` in IE9. So some custom solution is most likely needed

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `toFixed()` use `Math.ceil()` , `Math.floor()` or `Math.round()`

with a way around like

```
var rnum = 5.525,
    decimalPlaces = 2,
    factor = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces),
    newnumber = Math.round(rnum * factor) / factor,
    mydecimalvalue = parseFloat(newnumber);
```

the result is `5.53`

Comment: But these return integer values... how can it be used here?

Comment: After you multiply the number by 100, the number already loses the precision, so using those methods doesn't really help.

Comment: @rab nawaz khan : the result you got is 5.23 but it should be 5.53, so how can this is possible. This is way away from the expected result which should be 5.53

Answer (score 1):

Convert the number to String and work with it?

That is the last resort after I have tried to use Math.round, or simulate the nearest rounding with Math.ceil, but failed. When multiplying with 100, some number (such as 17.525) will be a bit less than 100 times its value (1752.5), while other numbers (such as 17.545) will be a bit more than 100 times its value (1754.5).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how converting the numbers to strings would help... just seems like more work.

Comment: We will work on the decimal representation instead of binary representation of the number. It is "visually correct" when we print the value before and after the rounding.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) and in options set `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` to the same number (number of digits you want to display).

```js
const formatter = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(
    (decimals) =>
        new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
            minimumFractionDigits: decimals,
            maximumFractionDigits: decimals,
        }),
);

console.log(formatter[2].format(17.525)); // 17.53
console.log(formatter[2].format(5.525)); // 5.53
console.log(formatter[2].format(1.005)); // 1.01
console.log(formatter[2].format(8.635)); // 8.64
console.log(formatter[2].format(8.575)); // 8.58
console.log(formatter[2].format(35.855)); // 35.86
console.log(formatter[2].format(859.385)); // 589.39
console.log(formatter[2].format(859.3844)); // 589.38
console.log(formatter[2].format(.004)); // 0.00
console.log(formatter[2].format(0.0000001)); // 0.00

// keep in mind that this will not be formatted as expected, as the value that
// you pass is actually 0.07499999999998863. 
console.log(formatter[2].format(239.575 - 239.5)); // 0.07
console.log(formatter[2].format(0.07499999999998863)); // 0.07
```

Comment: Try 41.354675 value with this formatter

Returns 41.35 :(