# Rounding issue in Math.round() & .toFixed()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used below two methods :

```
Number.prototype.myRound = function (decimalPlaces) {
    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);

    return (Math.round(this * multiplier) / multiplier);
};
alert((239.525).myRound(2));
```

Mathematically alert should be `239.53` but its giving `239.52` as output.
So i tried using `.toFixed()` function & i got proper answer.

But when i try to get answer for `239.575` it gives again wrong output.

```
alert((239.575).toFixed(2));
```

Here output should be `239.58` instead its giving `239.57`.

This error creating a bit difference in final output. So can anyone help me to sort this out?

Comment: Interesting but `239.375.toFixed(2)` returns `"239.38"` in Chrome 31 (Mac)... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [broken toFixed implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490687/broken-tofixed-implementation)

Comment: @VisioN Not here. Which browser are you using? I'm on the latest FF on Ubuntu.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach Chrome 31 on MacOS

Comment: Simpler solution:
[Truncate to decimals function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184500/2086460)

Comment: Simpler solution:
[Truncate to decimals function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184500/2086460)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This method will give very correct round result.

```
function RoundNum(num, length) { 
    var number = Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, length)) / Math.pow(10, length);
    return number;
}
```

Just call this method.

```
alert(RoundNum(192.168,2));
```

Comment: Its working fine. Its working for all conditions.
Thank you very much.

Comment: As mentioned by TJ Crowder in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015027/javascript-tofixed-not-rounding, try RoundNum(35.855, 2).
A better answer may be the Decimal Rounding Example in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: RoundNum(1.005,2) is rounded as 1, but expected 1.01

Answer (score 7):

Internally, 239.575 cannot be represented exactly. In binary, 0.575 would be something like 1/2 + 1/16 + 1/128 + 1/256 + ....

It just so happens that, represented in binary, the result is *slightly* less than 239.575. Therefore, `Math.round` rounds down.

To demonstrate, try this:

```
alert(239.575 - 239.5)
```

You would expect the result to be 0.075, but instead you get 0.07499999999998863.

Comment: Though it is true, I haven't ever seen such *'problems'* in other languages... That's definitely what must be improved in JavaScript.

Comment: @VisioN It's true of any language that uses double-precision floating-point numbers. Which is almost all of them, except those with fixed-point or arbitrary-precision systems.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Math.round`

```
function round(figureToRound){
    var roundOff = Math.round((figureToRound* 100 ).toFixed(2))/100;
    return roundOff;
}

console.log(round(1.005));
```

This will help the rounding off issue completely.

Comment: Works on all cases fro me.
    round(239.575 - 239.5) 0.08
    round(239.575) 239.58
    round(239.525) 239.53
    round(1.005) 1.01

Comment: Doesn't work for round(0.07499). It returns 0.08, instead of 0.07

Answer (score 2):

`round()` will do the trick.Try This:

```
var v= Math.round(239.575 * 100) / 100;
alert(v);
```

**[Working FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yJrMF/)**

Comment: this will not work with negative values for example -239.575 will give you -239.57 but it should be -239.58

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably floating point inaccuracy, thus you might get different results in different cases (different gathering of a number, different browsers etc.).

See also this: [toFixed(2) rounds "x.525" inconsistently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768083/tofixed2-rounds-x-525-inconsistently)

Answer (score 0):

In my software I use this:

(require [DecimalJS](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/))

```
Number.prototype.toFixed = function(fixed) {
    return (new Decimal(Number(this))).toFixed(parseFloat(fixed) || 
0);
};


var x = 1.005;
console.log( x.toFixed(2) ); //1.01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function bestRound(val, decimals){
    decimals = decimals || 2;
    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, decimals)
    return Math.round((val * multiplier ).toFixed(decimals)) / multiplier;
  }

bestRound(239.575 - 239.5)   0.08
bestRound(239.575)         239.58
bestRound(239.525)         239.53
bestRound(1.005)             1.01
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to simply overwrite it ->

```
Number.prototype.toFixed = function(fractionDigits, returnAsString = true) {
    var digits = parseInt(fractionDigits) || 0;
    var num = Number(this);
    if( isNaN(num) ) {
        return 'NaN';
    }
    
    var sign = num < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    if (sign < 0) { num = -num; }
    digits = Math.pow(10, digits);
    num *= digits;
    //num = Math.round(num.toFixed(12));
    num = Math.round( Math.round(num * Math.pow(10,12)) / Math.pow(10,12) );
    var ret = sign * num / digits;
    return (returnAsString ? ret.toString() : ret ); // tofixed returns as string always
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A method to deal only with this specific edge cases preserving the

```
function adjustRounding(number, fractionDigits) {
    let parts = number.toString().split('.');
    let fraction = parts[1];

    if (fraction && fraction.length > fractionDigits && fraction[fraction.length - 1] === '5') {
        number = parseFloat(parts[0] + '.' + fraction + '1');
    }

    return number.toFixed(fractionDigits);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

many answers here are working only with positive numbers but those solutions will fail with negative. for example -1.875 should return -1.88 not -1.87 so you need to check if number is negative and execute different logic

```js
function rounding(number) {
 if(number < 0) { // check if number is negative
   number = Math.abs(number); // remove minus from number to make it positive
   var roundedNumber = (Math.round(number * 100) / 100) * -1 // round it like positive but at the end multiple it -1 to make it negative again;
 } else {
   var roundedNumber = Math.round(number * 100) / 100
 }
 console.log(roundedNumber);
 return roundedNumber;
}

var number = 1.87501;

rounding(number);
```