# Issue in toFixed function of Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I find a biggest problem with toFixed(2) i.e. if i write 5.555 then it will display 5.55 and if I write 5.565 then it will display 5.57. What should I do?

This is what i am doing. Declaring one array and toFixed all values of first array and put in second array.

```
var arr1 = [25.205,25.215,25.225,25.235,25.245,25.255,25.265,25.275,25.285,25.295]

var arr2 = []

for(i=0;i<10;i++){ arr2[i]= +arr1[i].toFixed(2) }
```

Results:

```
arr1 = [25.205, 25.215, 25.225, 25.235, 25.245, 25.255, 25.265, 25.275, 25.285, 25.295]

arr2 = [25.2, 25.21, 25.23, 25.23, 25.25, 25.25, 25.27, 25.27, 25.29, 25.3]
```

should i have to use the `Math.floor()` method of the Math object for this.

```
Math.floor(number*100)/100
```

Comment: what output do you expect.. thats not an issue

Comment: *What should I do?* What do you think it should return?

Comment: I Have post some code. for values 25.225  and 25.235, after toFixed(2) it give result 25.23.

Comment: @KuashalKhamar It sure does, so what's the problem?

Comment: for 25.225 it gives 25.23. but for 25.235 it should give 25.24.

Comment: Hey that is strange. You should simplify your question a bit without the arrays etc... Heres the problem: `alert(2.225.toFixed(2)); /* <- 2.23, as expected (rounded up) */ alert(2.235.toFixed(2));  /* <- 2.23, expected 2.24 (rounded down) */ alert(2.245.toFixed(2));  /* <- 2.25, as expected (rounded up) */` Thats the main issue I'de like to know the answer to as well.

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz It should work like this
25.225 -> 25.23. 
25.235 -> 25.24

Comment: @KaushalKhamar read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12105938/3556874

Comment: possible duplicate of [toFixed javascript function giving strange results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105787/tofixed-javascript-function-giving-strange-results)

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.5 specifies 'exact mathematical value', so fractions ending in 5 should always round up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create a function which done all for me..

```
function toFixed(number, precision) {
    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision + 1),
        wholeNumber = Math.floor(number * multiplier);
    return Math.round(wholeNumber / 10) * 10 / multiplier;
}

//Call this function to retrive exect value
toFixed((+adjustmentval), 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the binary representations of the fractions being slightly more or less than the numbers entered. See the accepted answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701029/rounding-issue-in-math-round-tofixed) for an alternative method of rounding to 2 significant figures.