# js decimal precision toFixed() not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to roundOff value with precision 2.

Here is code snippet,

var value = 250.445;
var result = (value).toFixed(2);

result contains 250.44, after roundOff it should store 250.45,

I also tried this with directly typing in chrome's console. but still it shows 250.44 value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/number-tofixed-rounding-errors-broken-but-fixable/

Comment: toFixed will floor. not round. wich is pretty fine actually. this is not a bug.

Answer (score 2):

```
function round(num,dec)
{
  num = Math.round(num+'e'+dec)
  return Number(num+'e-'+dec)
}
```

> Usage: `alert(round(yourNumbber ,decimalsBehindYourNumber));`
>
> *example*: `alert(round(2.453,1))`

which means round 2.453 into 2.5

have a try!

[take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43012696/9589162)

Comment: Okay I will try, Thanks for your time

Comment: I updated my answer with example. Also, you can mark this as answered if this code works @user2781186

Comment: hi @user2781186 you may mark this as answered if you find this as a solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Math.round(your var or number);
```

or

```
Math.floor(your var or number);
```

```js
$('#teste').html(Math.round(245.655) + " - Round")
$('#testefloor').html(Math.floor(245.655) + " - Floor")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="teste"></label><br>
<label id="testefloor"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is, that tofixed() does not always round properly. 
This has already been ansered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701029/rounding-issue-in-math-round-tofixed/43557659) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015027/javascript-tofixed-not-rounding/43998255#43998255).

The main problem is, that the decimal 250.445 in binary is probably slightly less, leading it to round down the result. There are several self-written functions to address that. E. g.

```
function toFixed( num, precision ) {
    return (+(Math.round(+(num + 'e' + precision)) + 'e' + -precision)).toFixed(precision);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> var value = 250.445; var result = (value).toFixed(2);
>   result contains 250.44

250.44 is the absolute correct result, because there exists no exact representation of 250.445 in the computer. If reading 250.445 it is rounded to the nearest possible value = 250.444999999999993 (64 bit float). And rounding this number by toFixed(2) results in 250.44.

btw, 250.444999999999993 is internally stored as 0x406f4e3d70a3d70a and the next higher value is 0x406f4e3d70a3d70b == 250.445000000000022.

Answer (score 0):

toFixed() works correctly, but most people don't understand the problematic of the limited representation of floating point numbers.

Following the first link: 
239.575 is internally stored as 239.574999999999989 and rounding to 2 digits is 239.57 and not 239.58. All user defined replacement functions that have seen work wrong if you enter 239.5749999.