# Limit the number of decimals writen (js)

Tags: javascript

I got a minor brain-teaser thats keep bothering me. 
I'm unable to control the numbers of decimals written by my scripts.

HTML

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    <!--
    document.write($tekn_2_2/$tekn_2_1)
    //-->
</script>
```

JS

```
$tekn_2_1 = "28"
$tekn_2_2 = "7600"
```

I want this to return the value '271' instead of '271.42857142857144'.
I apologize, I'm aware that this should be a small case, but I can get anything to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Originally I had voted for toFixed but was not aware that this function also rounds. It looks like a simple floor is all that you need.

```
Math.floor($tekn_2_2/$tekn_2_1) == 271
```

Edit: +1 for Javascript: The Good Parts it goes over basic operations such as this. In a short but very informative manner.

[http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

Answer (score -1):

```
document.write(Math.round($tekn_2_2/$tekn_2_1));
```

Comment: This has the adverse affect of rounding up for some values instead of trimming off the decimal point.

Comment: toFixed() returns string. From mathematical point of view, I won't convert any mathematical result directly to string just because I want to write it to document. More information if you want to discover pitfalls of toFixed - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861055/using-tofixed2-and-math-round-to-get-correct-rounding

Comment: Good point I didn't realize that toFixed also rounded. Looks like we were both wrong on that one then and Floor was the correct answer.