# how to get the three decimal point of a no in javascript

Tags: javascript, decimal, number-formatting

So , i have a problem . i am calculating the discount and it may be in decimal points . the method i am using is not working for the value **0.0038575** and the method is

```
value=0.0038575
Math.round(value * 100) / 100,
```

it is returning the same value . this method is working for all other values . but the expected result is  **0.004**

now i changed the method i used this one **var discount = 0.0038575.toFixed(3);** working fine but the issue with this is it is not working if i pass the variable like below

```
var value=0.0038575;
var discount = value.toFixed(3);
```

error is **value.toFixed is not a function**i also tried this one for solve

```
var value=0.0038575;
var discount = "'"+value+"'".toFixed(3);
```

any help will be appreciated . thanx in advance

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q4zyb17u/

Comment: this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861055/using-tofixed2-and-math-round-to-get-correct-rounding

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: formatting a rounded number to N decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221167/javascript-formatting-a-rounded-number-to-n-decimals)

Comment: MDN's suggestion for a [`round10` decimal rounding function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me

```
var value = 0.0038575;
var loss = parseFloat(value).toFixed(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet works for me:

```js
var value = 0.0038575;
var discount = value.toFixed(3);
console.log(discount);
```

If your value is of type `string` you can try to cast it to a `number` with the `+` operator:

```
var discount = (+value).toFixed(3);
```

But without any reproducible code snippet I can only guess an answer.